# Car reaches a specific velocity through uniformly increasing acceleration in the first 9s and constant acceleration for the next 6s

Tags: calculus

the question is:

> A car starts from rest and reaches a speed of 42 m/s in
> 15 seconds. The acceleration (initially zero) increases uniformly for
> the first 9 seconds after which is remained constant.

I used $\frac{dA}{dt}= k,$ for the first 9 seconds since it says that the acceleration is uniformly increasing.

However, I have no way of finding the constant "k". If I start the solution in the part where the acceleration is constant I get: $42=V_0+a(6)$.

In here, I also have 2 unknowns. I am stuck with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The acceleration in the first $9$ seconds is $$a(t)=a(0)+kt=kt$$
After that, the acceleration is constant $$a(t>9)=k9$$
The velocity in the first $9$ seconds increases quadratically:
$$v(t<9)=\int_0^t a(t)dt=\frac k2 t^2$$
So at $t=9$ the velocity is $$v(9)=\frac k2 9^2$$
After that the velocity increases linearly:
$$v(t>9)=v(9)+a(9)\cdot (t-9)=\frac k2 9^2+k9(t-9)$$
So plug in $t=15$ to find $$v(15)=42=k\left[\frac129^2+9(15-9)\right]$$
You can now find $k$.

Comment: Don't forget to vote or accept the answer, if it proved useful.